# barplot x axis construction from data pandas seaborn python

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart, seaborn

So i'm trying to create a barplot using seaborn. My data is in the form

```
Packet number,Flavour,Contents
1,orange,4
2,orange,3
3,orange,2
4,orange,4
...
36, orange,3
1, coffee,5
2, coffee,3
...
1, raisin,4
etc.
```

My code is currently:

```
revels_data = pd.read_csv("testtt.txt") rd = revels_data

ax = sns.barplot(x="Packet number", y="Contents", data=rd) plt.show()
```

I'm trying to create bars for each packet number (on x axis) which are divided by colour inside each bar for the flavour with the total contents per packet on the y axis.

Started trying to make the totals of each packet i.e.

```
total_1 = (rd.loc[rd["Packet number"] == 1, "Contents"].sum())
```

but not sure how i'd go from there, or if there is an easier way to do it.

Any advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `hue` for that. As well, currently you are displaying the mean of each category. To calculate different function you can use `estimator`.

Thus, your code should be:

```
ax = sns.barplot(x="Packet number", y="Contents", hue="Flavour", data=rd)
```

Or if you want to show the sum instead of the mean:

```
ax = sns.barplot(x="Packet number", y="Contents", hue="Flavour", estimator=np.sum, data=rd)
```

---

**Edit**:

If you are interested in stacked barplot, you can make it directly using pandas, but you need to group your data first:

```
# Sum (or mean if you'd rather) the Contents per packet number and flavor
# unstack() will turn the flavor into columns, and fillna will put 0 in 
# all missing columns
grouped = rd.groupby(["Packet number", "Flavour"])["Contents"].sum().unstack().fillna(0)

# The x axis is taken from the index. The y axis from the columns
grouped.plot(kind="bar", stacked=True)
```

Comment: awesome, thankyou so much. how do i, instead of having multiple bars for each flavour, have a single bar with flavour divisions inside that 1 bar?

Comment: I don't think you can do it with seaborn. However, it is possible to do it directly with `pandas`. I'll add it to the post